# MongoDB findOne with multiple query returns wrong results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to query mongodb documents by passing two fields as arguments in a `findOne api`. Of the two fields passed to the the query statement only can be true at a time. the code is shown below.

```
//login user with phone or email
userSchema.statics.loginUser = async (userData) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    $or: [{ email: userData.email }, { phone: userData.phone }],
  });

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Wrong username or password one");
  }
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(userData.password, user.password);
  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error("Wrong username or password");
  }
  return user;
};
```

But i have noticed that even if i pass a non existent email of phone, the query always returns an existing document. What am i doing wrong in that query?

Comment: Could it be that `userData.email` or `userData.phone` is `null` and it is therefore matching a document that has a `null` `email` or `phone`? If so, you could try adding in a `$and` clause that checks the value isn't null as well as matches the parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also thought of this solution. I transformed the incoming data and removed the `undefined` data as shown below

```
 let username = {};
  username["email"] = userData.email;
  username["phone"] = userData.phone;

  Object.keys(username).forEach((key) =>
    username[key] === undefined ? delete username[key] : {}
  );

  const user = await User.findOne(username);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because `userData.email` or `userData.phone` is `null` and you have a document in your `User` collection that also has a `null` `email` or `phone`.

When I add the following three records to my database:

```
> db.User.insertMany([
... {email: "user1@example.com", phone: "555-1234"},
... {email: "user2@example.com", phone: null},
... {email: null, phone: "555-4321"}])
```

And then perform the following query using the email address of the first user:

```
> db.User.findOne({$or: [{ email: "user1@example.com" }, { phone: null }]})
```

I get back the expected record:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("600724ae7d009a501642a783"),
        "email" : "user1@example.com",
        "phone" : "555-1234"
}
```

But if I use the this query with an unknown email address:

```
> db.User.findOne({$or: [{ email: "user3@example.com" }, { phone: null }]})
```

Then I get the first document with a `null` `phone` because there's no match for the `email`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("600724ae7d009a501642a784"),
        "email" : "user2@example.com",
        "phone" : null
}
```

If I change my query to use an `$and` clause in each `$or` clause, I now get `null` when I use a value that doesn't exist and a `null` `phone`

```
> db.User.findOne({$or: [
...     { $and: [{ email: { $ne: null } }, { email: "user3@example.com" }] },
...     { $and: [{ phone: { $ne: null } }, { phone: null }] }
... ]})
```

```
null
```

And I can still find a record if it exists and is not `null`, for example this query:

```
> db.User.findOne({$or: [
...     { $and: [{ email: { $ne: null } }, { email: null }] },
...     { $and: [{ phone: { $ne: null } }, { phone: "555-1234" }] }
... ]})
```

Returns this one matching record:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("600724ae7d009a501642a783"),
        "email" : "user1@example.com",
        "phone" : "555-1234"
}
```